# jquery validate: dyanamically generated checkboxes (with not the same name)

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-validate

I'm using an older version of powermail extension in typo3.
This ext. creates the following markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="uid53_0" value="1" name="tx_powermail_pi1[uid53][0]">
<input type="checkbox" id="uid53_1" value="2" name="tx_powermail_pi1[uid53][1]">
<input type="checkbox" id="uid53_2" value="3" name="tx_powermail_pi1[uid53][2]">
```

So the names are not exactly the same.

I've tried this snippet to validate:

```
$('#formid').validate({
    rules: {
        'tx_powermail_pi1[uid53]': {
            required: true
        }
}
```

But sure, it's not working because of the numbers in the name attributes.

I thought maybe something like a wildcard `tx_powermail_pi1[uid53][*]` in the `rules:` part could help, but it does not.

I want that the a minimum of 1 checkbox in this group must be checked.

Comment: I'm not sure if it works but try [name^="tx_powermail_pi1"] otherwise give them a common class

Comment: The `rules` option will only accept rules declared by **one** full `name` at a time; by `id`, by `class`, by jQuery selector, and by wild-cards are all **not** allowed.  You must use the `.rules('add')` method inside of a jQuery `.each()`.  And since every checkbox has a different `name`, you must use the `require_from_group` rule.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to make one checkbox required out of a group (when each member of the group has a different `name`), use the `require_from_group` method that's part of [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js).

You can also save many lines of code by using [the `.rules()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules) inside a jQuery `.each()`.

Target all elements *starting with* `tx_powermail_pi1[uid53]`.

```
$('input[name^="tx_powermail_pi1[uid53]"]').each(function () {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        require_from_group: [1, this],
        messages: {
            require_from_group: "please check one"
        }
    });
});
```

Then to combine all three duplicate messages into one, use the `groups` option...

```
$('#formid').validate({
    // other rules & options
    groups: {
        checkbox: 'tx_powermail_pi1[uid53][0] tx_powermail_pi1[uid53][3] tx_powermail_pi1[uid53][4]'
    }
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/xLNVf/2/**